# How to link .o and rust .rlib when targeting risc-v?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, riscv

I am experimenting writing a program that can run on risc v directly without os, and I have successfully run one with asm and c, and now am trying to replace c with rust.
I created a cargo lib project and build it to .rlib, and when I want to link it with the .o generated from asm, it complains that core is not found.
here is the error

```
clang --target=riscv32 -nostdlib -fno-builtin -march=rv32imac -mno-relax -mabi=ilp32 -g -Wall -c -o target/boot.o src/boot.S
cargo build
ld.lld -Ttext=0x80000000 -o os.elf target/boot.o target/riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf/debug/libriscv_rust.rlib 
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: core::panicking::panic::h2e965d6649af1d40
>>> referenced by lib.rs:7 (src/lib.rs:7)
>>>               riscv_rust-8a999958878e9ee1.55nghx2crt3be19z.rcgu.o:(riscv_rust::add::h34f9c59c399fd8ab) in archive target/riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf/debug/libriscv_rust.rlib
```

and the files `boot.S`

```
.equ STACK_SIZE, 8192
.equ MAXNUM_CPU, 8

.global _start

.text
_start:
    csrr    t0, mhartid
    mv  tp, t0
    bnez    t0, park
    slli    t0, t0, 10
    la  sp, stacks + STACK_SIZE
    add sp, sp, t0
    j   start_kernel

park:
    wfi
    j   park

stacks:
    .skip   STACK_SIZE * MAXNUM_CPU
    .end
```

and `lib.rs`

```
#![no_std]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn start_kernel() {
    loop { }
}

#[panic_handler]
#[no_mangle]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop { }
}
```

and `.cargo/config.toml`

```
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf"
```

rust is compiled with nightly rustup